# SQL - Get data from Invoices table

Tags: sql, analytics

[image]I want to get from Invoices table those lines with having not correct math(if TotalPrice mathematically is correct) between TotalAmount,unitPrice and Quantity (example TotalAmount 10,unitPrice 4.9,quantity 2 is not correct math) Query should return All columns from Invoices table above. Can you please help to solve it by sql query?

Comment: Seems your question is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

just do what you are asking.

```
select
      i.*
   from
      invoice i
   where
      NOT i.TotalAmount = i.qty * i.unitPrice
```

Get all columns from the invoice table where the computation is NOT equal.  Now, you may need to apply round( i.qty * i.unitPrice, 2 ), but additionally, for items that have an odd value on either side that might result in a rounding error between the two.